# Wifi interface works but shows Ethernet Link type

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, arch-linux, wifi-driver

I am running Archlinux and have a working Wifi interface setup with netctl:

```
Description='Automatically generated profile by wifi-menu'
Interface=wlp3s0
Connection=wireless
Security=wpa
ESSID=ZyXEL3C58C2
IP=dhcp
Key=XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

However when I run `ip link`, the link type appears as link/ether:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp0s25: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f0:de:f1:d4:7e:89 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 10:0b:a9:c0:3b:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

This is usually not a problem, but I'm attempting to write networking software sensitive to different link types and the system returns `link/ether` instead of the expected `link/iee802.11`.

Why could this be occuring?

The computer is a Lenovo Thinkpad X220, using the iwlwifi and iwldvm modules for wireless networking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's normal. By default, Wi-Fi *is* meant to provide an Ethernet-compatible (well, 802.3-compatible) MAC layer. From IEEE 802.11-2016 ([free through IEEE GET](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7786995/)):

> **4.2.5 Interaction with other IEEE 802® layers**
>
> IEEE Std 802.11 is required to appear to higher layers [logical link control (LLC)] as a general-purpose IEEE 802 LAN.

So it's normal that higher-layer protocols treat Wi-Fi as Ethernet and the OS transparently rewrites the L2 header into a data frame. This even allows APs (such as your home router) to transparently bridge Wi-Fi to Ethernet with no additional effort.

For accessing Wi-Fi-specific features (e.g. WPA authentication by wpa_supplicant), Linux provides Netlink APIs (nl80211) as well as obsolete WEXT ioctls. See the source code of `iw`, `wpa_supplicant`, and `iwd` for examples – or in fact, consider whether you can do what you want using wpa_supplicant's own API.

---

To send and receive *real* 802.11 frames, enable monitor mode for the interface:

```
iw phy phy0 interface add mon0 type monitor
iw dev mon0 set monitor control otherbss
iw dev mon0 set channel 11
ip link set mon0 up
```

Result:

```
8: mon0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ieee802.11/radiotap 48:5d:60:e8:65:8f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

See [aircrack-ng documentation](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=injection_test) for one possible packet-injection tool.

Note that *not all* WLAN adapters support packet injection, or even monitor mode in general. (You'll have better luck with "SoftMAC" devices such as ath9k, than "FullMAC" ones as they handle everything in firmware. I still haven't figured out how to make my iwlwifi display beacon frames.)